# Loading PNGs with CImg

Tags: png, zlib, libpng, cimg

I am unable to load PNGs with CImg. I've heard you need to get libpng / zlib to get to work first but I am unsure how to set this up. I am on Ubuntu. My source:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

#define cimg_using_png
#include "CImg.h"
using namespace cimg_library;
#include "png.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    CImg<unsigned char> img2("test.png");
    img2.display();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Close, but you need `#define cimg_use_png`

and add `-lpng` to your linker flags.