# How to add linker flags in Visual C++ 2010?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, linker

I try to follow the solution to this question:

[Using pHash from .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6254447/using-phash-from-net)

which lead me to:

[Loading PNGs with CImg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4001816/loading-pngs-with-cimg)

I have define cimg_use_png in Project properties > Configuration Properties > C / C++ > Preprocessor > Edit Preprocessor Definitions

[image]

But how do I add -lpng to the linker flags ?

I tried to add it to Linker > Command Line like this:
[image]

But I got this warning: 
1>LINK : warning LNK4044: unrecognized option '/lpng'; ignored

Comment: Visual Studio doesn't work that way.  You would want to add the library as an additional dependency in the Linker->Input property page.  It would seem you have already done so as libpng.lib is listed in the command line.

Comment: @RetiredNinja: thanks, but it still crash when opening png file. Maybe the error lies elsewhere. Can you make your comment an answer so I can accept it ?

Comment: You have to place libpng.dll ( and all dependent dlls) parallel to your application

Comment: @PankajM: I have done that. The crash is from png_read_info in Cimg